# @(Html.Kendo() is not recognised by intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo.Mvc dll and below is my `.cshtml`

```
    @using Kendo.Mvc.UI
    @model SupplierPortal.RedirectionApp.Models.SiteDetailViewModel
    @using System.Web.Optimization
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = null;
    }
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@*<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
@*<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />*@
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SupplierPortal.RedirectionApp.Models.SiteDetailViewModel>()
                      .Name("Grid")
                      .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                          columns.Bound(p => p.name).Title("Name");
                          columns.Bound(p => p.gender).Title("Gender");
                          columns.Bound(p => p.designation).Title("Designation").Width("300px");
                          columns.Bound(p => p.department).Title("Department").Width("300px");
                      })

                      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                      .Navigatable()
                      .Pageable()
                      .Sortable()
                      .Scrollable()
                      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource // Configure the grid data source
                      .Ajax()
                      .Model(model =>
                      {
                          //model.Id(x => x.id);
                      })
                          .Read(read => read.Action("Employee_Read", "Home")) // Set the action method which will return the data in JSON format
                       )
        )
    </div>
```

Below is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    string nasaUserId = "vlc00072";
    var _prd = _redirectionService.GetSiteDetailsForAppUser(nasaUserId);
    _siteDetailViewModel.SiteDetailList = _prd;
    return Json(_siteDetailViewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have also added `Kendo.MVC` reference in `Views Web.Config` like below

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="SupplierPortal.RedirectionApp" />
    <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc" />

</namespaces>
```

and in main web.config file

```
  <system.web>   
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" >
<assemblies>       
    <add assembly="Kendo.Mvc" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
```

can someone let me where I am doing wrong and why razor is not recognizing the `@Html.Kendogrid()` and I have also included the dll in reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Kendo.mvc.dll` given by Telerik team. I was having the same problem by installing Kendo.MVC from nuget but it was not recognising then i have added `.dll` given by Telerik team. now it's working. [Here is the link](https://www.telerik.com/download-trial-file/v2/ui-for-asp.net-mvc) to download trial version and you will find the `Kendo.Mvc.dll` in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2016\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries** location after installing.